# Query Custom post types via AJAX on multilingual site

Tags: php, sql, ajax, wordpress

I have to get some CPTs through AJAX request on a multi language site.(Polylang plugin)
I'm using the `WP_Query( $args )` class, but it doesn't return me anything.
The same class working from my functions.php page and returns the expected result.

I checked the auto generated SQL what's been used in both queries and they are different.

The working SQL targeting a sub table `wp_3_posts` which contains the translated CPT(i recon).

I believe the one which was called from the functions.php working, because Wordpress or the plugin recognise that this is a Multi site and change the SQL.

My question is: How can i query custom table or how can i add any extra info to my $args that will effect the SQL query?

Comment: It probably can’t determine the language, because the AJAX request URL does not contain that information. (Are you using (sub-)domains, or a path prefix in your URLs?) Try and specify the language explicitly with your request, see https://polylang.pro/doc/developpers-how-to/#ajax

Comment: Hi, i tried to specify  $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'post_type_name',
            'orderby' => 'event_start_date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'lang' => 'de',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'event_start_date',
                    'value' => array($start_date, $end_date),
                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                )
            )

        ); no luck

Comment: I found other sources saying the language must be set as path prefix in the AJAX request URL, and others suggesting to take it from a cookie (and then set it explicitly when using `pll_get_post`, but that’s not what you are using here, and I did not see a function to _set_ the language the plugin is supposed to be working in) … Your best bet is probably to contact the manufacturer for support, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the support, i try to get in touch with them. Can't make it work on my own(